# How do I use a for loop in a vending machine with a three choice limit?

Tags: java

Don't think this is correct, how would I use the for loop? I need to use all while, and for loops and if statements.

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    final double POTATO_CHIPS_PRICE = 1.25;
    final double SNICKERS_PRICE = 0.80;
    final double KIND_BAR_PRICE = 0.70;
    int snackSelection = 0;

    // final int POTATO_CHIPS = A1,A2,A3;

    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    System.out.println("              Snack Machine                ");
    System.out.println("*******************************************");
    System.out.println("Potato Chips   Potato Chips  Potato Chips");
    System.out.println("A1  $1.25      A2  $1.25     A3  $1.25   ");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Snickers       Snickers      Snickers ");
    System.out.println("B1  $0.80      B2  $0.80     B3  $0.80");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Kind Bar       Kind Bar      Kind Bar");
    System.out.println("C1  $0.70      C2  $0.70     C3  $0.70");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("How many snacks would you like?  Limit is 3:");
    snackSelection = sc.nextInt();

    for (double snack <= 1; snack < 3; snack++) {
        System.out.println("Enter snack selection:");
```

}

Comment: What do you actually want this to do? Why are you asking how to use a for loop instead of telling us what you want to do, instead of how. Also, you're using a double instead of an int in the for-loop.

Comment: I'm creating a loop that waits for a customer and runs until the vending machine is shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Im going to assume you want your user to select three types snacks. If the user has to select specific number of snacks you can use a for loop, however a whileloop would be better in most cases since you can better control when the loop will end.

For example, if the user doesnt type in a correct type of snack, a for loop will still iterate and as result a user might end up with less than three snacks.

Using a for loop would be something like this

```
int amount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   println("What snack would you like?");
   String selection = sc.nextLine();
   if (!selection.equals("A1") || !!selection.equals("B2") ||!!selection.equals("C3")) {
       println("Undefined snack, please select A1, B1 or C1")
   } else {
       if(selection.equals("A1") {
         amount += POTATO_CHIPS_PRICE;
       } else if (selection.equals("B2") {
         amount += SNICKERS_PRICE;
       } else {
         amount += KIND_BAR_PRICE;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add support for the other amounts/prices but thats part of the fun! Also this is Java not JavaScript! Easily and commonly confused.

```java
    static final List<String> VALID_SNACKS = Arrays.asList("A1", "B1", "C1");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println("              Snack Machine                ");
        System.out.println("*******************************************");
        System.out.println("Potato Chips   Potato Chips  Potato Chips");
        System.out.println("A1  $1.25      A2  $1.25     A3  $1.25   ");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Snickers       Snickers      Snickers ");
        System.out.println("B1  $0.80      B2  $0.80     B3  $0.80");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Kind Bar       Kind Bar      Kind Bar");
        System.out.println("C1  $0.70      C2  $0.70     C3  $0.70");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int amount = -1;

        while (amount == -1) {
            System.out.println("How many snacks would you like?  Limit is 3:");

            int input = scanner.nextInt();

            if (input < 1 || input > 3) {
                System.out.println("You can only have 1 to 3 stacks.");
                continue;
            }
            amount = input;
        }
        String type = null;

        while (type == null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("What type of snack do you want %s of?", amount));

            String input = scanner.next();

            int indexOfType = VALID_SNACKS.indexOf(input);

            if (indexOfType == -1) {
                System.out.println("That is not a valid snack.");
                continue;
            }
            type = input;
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Okay! %sx %s coming right up!", amount, type));
    }
```

Comment: too complex, this is for a beginners class. only can use what I've listed in the title

Comment: This uses for-loop and if statements.

Comment: Removed usage of recursion and replaced with while-loop.

Comment: we don't use type, static final, continue, null, or index of type

Comment: Yikes, can't imagine being confined to such a small box.

Comment: That's why it's an entry level class haha